# Can I import my Ionic project to Android Studio, then use Crosswalk?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I know Crosswalk shared mode does not yet support Cordova. But can I import my Ionic project to Android Studio, then use Crosswalk shared mode or Crosswalk lite on that? How can I get Crosswalk working in this way?

Comment: Why vote down? is something wrong in my question?

Comment: You might have been voted down because your question wasn't entirely clear. I tried to reword it a little for clarity, and gave you an up vote to balance it out, but I would still recommend you add some details to your post to clarify exactly what you're asking.